# fullcalendar - how to render only actived resource events at agenda weekly view?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar, resource-id

please help.

this is following my code..

i'm working fullcalendar.js library

**how to render only resourceId "A" resource events at agenda weekly view?**

now working all events rendered.

i want render by resourceId events

```
$(Calendar).fullCalendar({
 resources: [
  {
   id: "A",
   title: "R-A"
  },
  {
    id: "B",
    title: "R-B"
  }
 ],
  events: [
   {
    "id": "0", 
    "resourceId": "A"
  },{
    "id": "1", 
    "resourceId": "B"
  }
 ],
  views: {
   agendaWeekly: {
    days: 7 
   } 
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not quite what you're asking for, but if you define the render function as follows, it will remove all events that arent of ID "A" when it starts rendering:

```
$(Calendar).fullCalendar({

   ...
  eventRender : function(event, element,view) {
     if (event.resourceId != "A") {
        $(Calendar).fullCalendar("removeEvents",event._id);
     }
   },
  ...

});
```

Comment: maybe a solution this way also. but
i want another standard solutions or fullcalendar option